# windows administration - setting up alerts/emails for failed windows services

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, service, monitoring

What are some best practices, tools sets within the Windows 2003 server that I can utilize to monitor failed application services?

We basically have some 3party software that has a few services that it runs. I also want to be notified if the IIS server goes down as well.

I am not interested in obtaining other software for this. If I have to figure out and script in, I would rather do it that way.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the best way to do this given the constraints you mention is *eventtriggers.exe*.

You create a trigger for the event you want to monitor, which then calls a mailer script of some kind.

Look at this excellent [article](http://www.petri.co.il/how-to-use-eventtriggersexe-to-send-e-mail-based-on-event-ids.htm) for more details.

and the [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490901.aspx).

Comment: very interesting..will definitely take a look at this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can script the Windows WMI monitors, see for example

http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Documentation/Nagios-XI-Documentation/Monitoring-Windows-With-WMI/details